# Pipelines Powershell Task - One session across mutliple tasks

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

Is it possible to persist one session between multiple Powershell tasks in the same Agent Job? My intention is to sign in to Az module and Azure CLI in the first task and not have to authenticate again in subsequent tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> Pipelines Powershell Task - One session across mutliple tasks

I am afraid there is no such way to persist one session between multiple Powershell tasks in the same Agent Job.

As we know, one task one session. When we create a connection in one Powershell tasks, we could access the server in this task all the time. But when this task is completed, the session will be closed and the connection will be disconnected. Otherwise we need to keep this session all the time until we to close it manually, obviously this is extremely unsafe.

To resolve this issue, you could add one powershell task to authenticate, then invoke other powershell in this powershell task, so that you do not need to authenticate again. But if you want keep the authentication for multiple Powershell tasks in the same Agent Job, I am afraid this is not feasible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You say "As we know, one task one session", how do we know this? Where is this documented, or is this just assumed internal Microsoft knowledge?